# customize jquery accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm new to jQuery UI and I just started with an accordion example.
I want to place an image or icon in the title next to the title text.
Can someone please let me know how to do it?

Comment: Are you using a specific pre-made accordion plugin already, or is this from scratch? (Please provide any code or sources possible for a more specific answer from the community.)

Comment: I'm using a basic accordion styled with Cupertino theme.

Comment: You can style it as in the answer below or with a background-image, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4MKHd/3/  Btw, does anybody know, why there must be used 1,3,5,7 indexes for h3:nth-child? I expected using 1,2,3,4..... ???

Comment: I used a background image but it cleared part of the image used for the background of the title. I'll use the answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, the accordation is unstyled, but you can see the white images, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4MKHd/)

Comment: Is possible to turn it in a properties/something else? just to simplify the adding and removing the image ... just like: {title_image: img.jpg }